# ggplot 2: dot plot with mean and 95% CI for two grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a dot plot and add the mean and 95% CI for two independent grouping variables (so I have 2 x 2 groups in total).

This is my data:

```
GluNorm Gender  Treatment
1.317   Male    NAC
1.278   Male    SAL
1.302   Male    SAL
1.376   Male    NAC
1.279   Male    NAC
1.308   Male    SAL
1.451   Male    NAC
1.244   Male    NAC
1.411   Male    SAL
1.16    Male    NAC
1.159   Male    NAC
1.42    Male    SAL
1.407   Male    SAL
1.62    Male    SAL
1.167   Male    SAL
1.377   Male    NAC
1.393   Female  SAL
1.203   Female  NAC
1.191   Female  NAC
1.132   Female  SAL
1.191   Female  SAL
1.589   Female  SAL
1.169   Female  NAC
1.155   Female  SAL
1.249   Female  NAC
1.401   Female  NAC
1.455   Female  SAL
1.481   Female  SAL
1.293   Female  NAC
1.332   Female  NAC
1.462   Female  SAL
```

This is what I would like the plot to look like:

[image: fig1]

I  made the following attempt:

```
g<- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Gender, y = GluNorm, fill=Group))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',stackratio=1.2, dotsize=1.2, binwidth=0.02, position=position_dodge(0.8)) 


#function that outputs mean, lower limit and upper limit of 95% CI
data_summary <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  sem <-sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))
  ymin<-m-1.96*sem
  ymax<-m+1.96*sem
  return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
}

g +  stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, color="red")
```

And get the following result:

[image: fig2]

Could anyone advise on how to get separate dots and bars for each gender x treatment group?

Thanks!

Comment: you can try adding a position argument like so: `stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, color="red", position = position_dodge(width = .75))`

Comment: Did you mean `fill=Treatment`, which would make the code consistent with your data sample?

Answer (score 4):

The graph will be easier to read if you dodge the doplots and the confidence intervals by different amounts, so that the don't overlap:

```
pd1 = position_dodge(0.2)
pd2 = position_dodge(0.65)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Gender, y = GluNorm, fill=Treatment, color=Treatment))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',stackratio=1.2, 
               dotsize=0.8, binwidth=0.02, position=pd2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, position=pd1, geom="errorbar", width=0.05) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, position=pd1, geom="point", size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 100, 60)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 50, 40)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Instead of your `data_summary` function, you could also use built-in functions. Below we get the 95% CI using bootstrapping:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Gender, y = GluNorm, fill=Treatment, color=Treatment))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',stackratio=1.2, 
               dotsize=0.8, binwidth=0.02, position=pd2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, position=pd1, geom="errorbar", width=0.05) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position=pd1, geom="point", size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 100, 60)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 50, 40)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Instead of a dotplot, you could also just plot the points directly, adding jitter to avoid overlap:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Gender, y = GluNorm, fill=Treatment, color=Treatment))+
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.65, jitter.height=0, jitter.width=0.25),
             alpha=0.7) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.05, position=pd1) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", size=2, position=pd1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 100, 60)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 50, 40)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or maybe a boxplot:

```
pd1 = position_dodge(0.4)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Gender, y = GluNorm, fill=Treatment, color=Treatment))+
  geom_boxplot(position=pd1, width=0.3, alpha=0.2, color="#00000080", 
               lwd=0.4, fatten=1.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.1, position=pd1, size=0.7) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", size=2, position=pd1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 100, 80)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195), 50, 30)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, I'm going to use geom_point as you suggest. I did mean fill = Treatment, sorry for the confusion.